# Finding the name of an object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have some Javascript with the following:

```
Foo = {
    alpha: { Name: "Alpha", Description: "Ipso Lorem" },
    bravo: { Name: "Bravo", Description: "Nanu, Nanu" },
    delta: { Name: "Fly with me", Description: "Klaatu barata nikto" }
};

Table = [ Foo.alpha, Foo.bravo, Foo.delta];

x = Table[1];
```

Is there any way of looking at `x` and getting the identifier `bravo`? I'm fully aware that I can use `x.Name` or `x.Description`, but let's say that I need to know the name for something elsewhere. In one task I experimented with, I was forced to add a redundant `id : "bravo"` to each entry, but that was a pain.

My gut tells me it can't be done. But I'm hoping someone else can tell me otherwise.

Comment: No, not with that code - `add a redundant id` - it's not redundant if you need it

Comment: You could go crazy and make a function that turns each of the properties into getters that automatically add the `id: "xxx"` part to the object, but there is no way around it; only methods to minimize the redundancy.

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done with something like obj._myOldKey_ as far as I know. You could iterate over "Foo" to find the key of the matching object however this might take time. Easier to package the id as you have mentioned before.

Comment: You may add an `id` or `key` into each value within `Foo` like this: `Object.entries(Foo).forEach(([k, v]) => Foo[k] = {...v, id: k});`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, everyone. As I suspected, the real answer is "sorta." Thanks to Hiritik Sharma. I think that's the best that can be done. jsN00b's variant is good. I'll use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Foo = {
    alpha: { Name: "Alpha", Description: "Ipso Lorem" },
    bravo: { Name: "Bravo", Description: "Nanu, Nanu" },
    delta: { Name: "Fly with me", Description: "Klaatu barata nikto" }
};

Table = [ ];
for(let val in Foo){
  let obj = Foo[val];
  obj = {...obj , id:val }
  Table.push(obj)
}
x = Table[1];
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) ...

```js
const _Foo = {
    alpha: { Name: "Alpha", Description: "Ipso Lorem" },
    bravo: { Name: "Bravo", Description: "Nanu, Nanu" },
    delta: { Name: "Fly with me", Description: "Klaatu barata nikto" }
};
const Foo = new Proxy(_Foo, {
    get(target, id) {
        if (target.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
           return {...target[id], id};
        }
        return target[id];
    }
});
const Table = [ Foo.alpha, Foo.bravo, Foo.delta ];
console.log(Table[0])
```

Comment: What is notable about this solution is that it does not alter the original object (named: `_Foo`) and rather creates a new `Proxy` (named: `Foo`). The idea shared on the comment by me fails to retain the original object as-is. +1 @Bravo !